# How to get the effect not to add one more div?

Tags: html, css

What I want to get the effect is as following:

[image]

I can't get it with my CSS code (Code 1):

```css
#content{
  position:relative;
  width:873px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_left{
  float:left;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_right{
  float:left;
  width:469px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">content
  <div id="content_left">content_left
  </div>
  <div id="content_right">content_right
  </div>
</div>
```

What I get is the following:
[image]

I can add `div` to pack the content and get the effect (Code 2):

```css
#content{
  width:873px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#up {
  width:873px;
  height:30px;
}
#content_left{
  float:left;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_right{
  float:left;
  width:469px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="up">content</div>
  <div id="content_left">content_left
  </div>
  <div id="content_right">content_right
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is: If I don't add one more `div` to pack the text `content`, how to fix Code 1 to get the desired result?

Comment: Remove the width from the `.up` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For (code1)*

---

`table-cell` could help instead `float`

```css
#content {
           width: 873px;
           border: 1px solid red;
         }
         #content_left {
           width: 400px;
         }
         #content_right {
           width: 469px;
         }
         #content_left,
         #content_right {
           display: table-cell;
           /*border: 1px solid red;*/
           box-shadow: -1px -1px red;/* redrawn borders */
           height: 300px;
           margin: 0;
         }
```

```html
<div id="content">content
  <div id="content_left">content_left
  </div>
  <div id="content_right">content_right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original markup, your content text is part of the content div along with the content_left div which you are floating left. You need to remove the "content" div and put it before the other divs.

```
<div id="content">
    content
</div>
<div id="content_left">content_left</div>
<div id="content_right">content_right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the Code 1 working:

http://codepen.io/jacob-on-codepen/pen/pygrrP

HTML

```
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="content_left">content_left
</div>
<div id="content_right">content_right
</div>
```

I moved #content_left and #content_right out of #content.

CSS

```
#content{
  position:relative;
  width:873px;
  height:25px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_left{
  float:left;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_right{
  float:left;
  width:469px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

I made no changes to the CSS, other than #content's height.

Your other divs were inside of your #content div, that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can just wrap the `content_left` and `content_right`

```css
#content{
  position:relative;
  width:873px;
  height:330px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_left{
  float:left;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_right{
  float:left;
  width:469px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  content
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content_left">content_left
    </div>
    <div id="content_right">content_right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```